# Bulk mailing in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, massmail

I want to send promotional emails to all my clients. i have txt file with all email lists.

bellow is my code to send email but this code is working sometimes only and sometimes its not working.

Sample for text file:

```
abc@abc.com
xyz@xyz.com
hello@xyz.com
```

and so on.

This file is stored in root directory.

now my controller's code.

```
$file = fopen("10.txt", "r");
$str = "";
$i = 0;
while (!feof($file)) {
  if($i != 0){ $str .= ","; }else{ $i++;}
  $str .= fgets($file);
}
fclose($file);
$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->clear(TRUE);
$this->email->from('email-id@email.com', 'Name Here');
$this->email->to('email-id@email.com'); 
$this->email->bcc($str); 
$this->email->set_mailtype("html");
$this->email->subject('Subject here');
$message = $this->load->view('email-template', '' , true);  
$this->email->message($message);    
$this->email->send();
```

Can you please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Looks like all you need to do is $this->email->to($str);

Comment: @killstreet still not working

Comment: in this text file i have 1000 emails @killstreet

Comment: It looks like it's caused by an unexpected " , " at the end, have a look if there indeed is a comma at the end of the variable $str, if so remove that and check it again.

Comment: You close the file handle as soon as you open it... what do you expect it to do?

Comment: I'd never recommend sending that many emails at once, I'd only do 20 at a time max (personal preference). It might help lowering the amount of emails being sent at once too.

Comment: @JonStirling he is putting it in a variable, the variable $file will still have all the content.

Comment: @killstreet Um... no.

Comment: @JonStirling i stored all the content of 10.txt file in $file variable .

Comment: @darshan No you haven't. fopen gives you a resource, a pointer to the file, not the content. fgets then uses the pointer to get the content, but you've already closed it.

Comment: @killstreet it takes lots of time to do so i need some solution to send mail to 1000 email id by only one click.

Comment: @JonStirling yes you are right my mistake edited my question but still this code is working for only sometimes.

Comment: When it doesn't work, how do you know?  What are you seeing? Does it work for the first 5 emails then not?

Comment: sometimes it is working for all email ids sometimes it works for first 5 6 emails and sometimes its not working for all.

Comment: Maybe some server limitation? Have you considered of third party like Mandrill etc?